# Google Docs Notification 10 minutes too late?

Tags: google-docs, notifications

I am using Google Docs together with my father. When I add a comment somewhere he gets instantly an email that I have added something. When he adds a comment I get an email always about 10 minutes later.

Is this a setting that I can config somewhere?

I have a gmail email (example@gmail.com) and I am logged in at gmail. There is to redirecting of the email that could explain the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no configuration exists for that anywhere. This is beyond user setup options. Delay could be caused fully on Google side, but there are also "other" factors which can cause such behavior like:

- delay in synchronization
- desktop to android (vice versa)
- internet / ISP issues
- difference in protocols (this one you can check in Gmail settings)